# Find longest path in 2d array first increasing then decreasing

Tags: c, path

I have a 2D array like this:

```
 3525  2227 35951  9308

42730 58974 32071 45993

41551 36086 19433 15661

60446 11397  2764 12939
```

I have to find the longest path in this array with numbers first increasing and then decreasing. I know the correct answer is 2764 -> 12939 -> 15661 -> 19433 -> 32071 -> 58974 -> 42730 -> 41551 -> 36086 -> 11379. All I need to know is the length (10), not the path itself. I have already tried bitonic sequence, but no luck there.

Comment: How would you solve it by hand?

Comment: That's the problem. I have no problem finding the longest path with increasing numbers. I created a graph from the array and found out that the longest path is 2764->12939->15661->19433->36086->41551->42730->58974 (one of the options). Finding the decreasing sequence is the problem.

Comment: You're going to need to be able to print the path during debugging to determine whether you've got the right answer or not.  If you're looking at cell (i,j), you've got 4 possible directions to look — left, right, up, down.  Sometimes, when the current cell is on the edge, there'll be no cell in some directions.  Also, you'll either be working on the up or the down path.

Comment: For each available direction, you have 3 states: (1) already on path, so not available; (2) cell is larger, so if you're working down, no use; if you're working up, try from the new cell; otherwise, no use; (3) cell is smaller, so if you're working up, no use; if you're working down, try from new cell.  You need to keep a record of the current path and its length.  Presumably, going up requires at least 2 numbers, and going down requires at least two numbers.  This will probably be recursive with backtracking.